# GIS and/or Maps regarding Ginseng in the United States.

Tags: geospatial

Does anyone know of any spatial data on Ginseng in the United States other than USGS range maps?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Availability, planting regions, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Have you google it ? I ran and found this but not sure if this what you are looking for. You might want to give them a call to nail it down where you can get the data for Ginseng.  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3825865/